# Polly patterns in C# for a workflow?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, fallback, polly, retry-logic

I have a workflow like this:

- call an API method

  - if any exception is thrown but timeout, the program logs that exception and throws it.
- if timeout is thrown, the program has to call another API method.

  - after calling another API method, if everything goes true, the program returns a result.
  - otherwise the program throws an exception and log it.

both API methods have the same type of result.
I want to implement this with polly policies.

This is my sample code:

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
    .RetryAsync(1, async (exception, retryCount) =>
        await CallAnotherAPI());

var fallbackPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .FallbackAsync((r, c, ct) => throw r.Exception,
    async (r, c) =>
    {
        Log(r.Message);
    });

var result = await fallbackPolicy
    .WrapAsync(retryPolicy)
    .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        await CallAPI();
    });
```

but it doesn't work and all the time fallbackPolicy is executed. How can I write the code that if retryPolicy goes true, fallbackPolicy won't be executed?

Comment: Probably typo: `await CallAnotherAPI();.ConfigureAwait(false)` <= ";" before "."?

Comment: `.ExecuteAsync(async () => {  CallAPI();  }`isn't this missing `await`?

Comment: I corrected them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your workflow correctly then you don't need the retry policy at all. The Fallback policy is enough for this.

So, let suppose that the `CallApi` and `CallAnotherApi` are implemented like this:

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAPI()
{
    return await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us//408");
}

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAnotherAPI()
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us//500");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return response;
}
```

- I've used `httpstatus.us` to simulate certain http status codes
- `CallApi` will always fail with Request Timeout
- `CallAnotherApi` will always throw `HttpRequestException` because of the `Ensure` method call

Now let's see the policy definition and usage:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var fallbackPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .HandleResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
    .FallbackAsync(async (_) => await CallAnotherAPI());

    HttpResponseMessage result;
    try
    {
        result = await fallbackPolicy
            .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {
                return await CallAPI();
            });
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //TODO: replace with logging
        throw;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
}
```

- The fallback policy should be triggered only if the response's status code was 408
- `ExecuteAsync` will throw exception if either the `CallApi` or `CallAnotherApi` throws

---

Let's see the different scenarios one-by-one

#### `CallApi` succeeds

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAPI()
{
    return await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us//200");
}
```

Output

```
OK
```

#### `CallApi` fails

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAPI()
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us//500");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return response;
}
```

Output

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

Then the application crashes because of `throw;`

#### `CallApi` timeouts and `CallAnotherApi` succeeds

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAPI()
{
    return await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us//408");
}

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAnotherAPI()
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us//200");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return response;
}
```

Output

```
OK
```

#### `CallApi` timeouts and `CallAnotherApi` fails

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAPI()
{
    return await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us//408");
}

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAnotherAPI()
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://httpstat.us//500");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return response;
}
```

Output

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

Then the application crashes because of `throw;`

Answer (score 1):

The polly fallback is enough in this case. like this....

```
var fallbackPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
.Handle<Exception>()
.FallbackAsync((r, c, ct) => throw r.Exception,
async (r, c) =>
{
    Log(r.Message);
});
```